# reshaping tensor and keep the original relative position of the elements unchanged in numpy (or tensorflow) tensor

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, reshape, tensor

I have a tensor like this :

```
A=array([[[[ 1.4033688 , -0.95642966,  1.0958625 , -0.64104766],
         [-1.2625898 , -0.59444463,  0.72382635, -0.5195144 ],
         [ 0.15248759,  2.4054656 ,  1.0738292 ,  1.0531213 ],
         [ 1.2878437 , -1.1945801 , -1.0729346 , -1.6739473 ]],

        [[ 0.        , -0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ],
         [-0.        , -0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        , -0.        , -0.        , -0.        ]]],


       [[[ 0.        , -0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ],
         [-0.        , -0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        , -0.        , -0.        , -0.        ]],

        [[ 1.4033688 , -0.95642966,  1.0958625 , -0.64104766],
         [-1.2625898 , -0.59444463,  0.72382635, -0.5195144 ],
         [ 0.15248759,  2.4054656 ,  1.0738292 ,  1.0531213 ],
         [ 1.2878437 , -1.1945801 , -1.0729346 , -1.6739473 ]]]],
      dtype=float32)
```

In particular,

```
A[0][0]=[[ 1.4033688 , -0.95642966,  1.0958625 , -0.64104766],
             [-1.2625898 , -0.59444463,  0.72382635, -0.5195144 ],
             [ 0.15248759,  2.4054656 ,  1.0738292 ,  1.0531213 ],
             [ 1.2878437 , -1.1945801 , -1.0729346 , -1.6739473 ]]
A[1][0]=[[[ 0.        , -0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ],
             [-0.        , -0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ],
             [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
             [ 0.        , -0.        , -0.        , -0.        ]]
A[0][1]=[[[ 0.        , -0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ],
             [-0.        , -0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ],
             [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
             [ 0.        , -0.        , -0.        , -0.        ]]
A[1][1]=[[ 1.4033688 , -0.95642966,  1.0958625 , -0.64104766],
             [-1.2625898 , -0.59444463,  0.72382635, -0.5195144 ],
             [ 0.15248759,  2.4054656 ,  1.0738292 ,  1.0531213 ],
             [ 1.2878437 , -1.1945801 , -1.0729346 , -1.6739473 ]]
```

I want to reshape A into an (8 , 8) array such that I keep the positions of the elements as if the array  just removed the intermediate brackets. In other words, after reshaping A into the new array, let's call this new reshaped array `A_reshaped`, then I want `A_reshaped` to be equal to A in the following

```
A_reshaped[:4,:4]=A[0][0]
A_reshaped[4:8,0:4]=A[1][0]
A_reshaped[:4,4:8]=A[0][1]   
A_reshaped[4:8,4:8]=A[1][1]
```

The straightforward command :

```
np.reshape(A,(8,8))[:4,:4]
```

does not work and it yields the following results :

```
array([[ 1.4033688 , -0.95642966,  1.0958625 , -0.64104766],
       [ 0.15248759,  2.4054656 ,  1.0738292 ,  1.0531213 ],
       [ 0.        , -0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]],
      dtype=float32)
```

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: What's the original shape?  (2,2,4,4)?  You can reshape it to (4,4,4).  To get a (8,8) you need to first transpose so the shape is (2,4,2,4)

Answer (score 0):

Using `gather_nd()`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
input1 = tf.constant([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
input2 = tf.constant([[4, 5], [6, 7]])
input3 = tf.constant([[8, 9], [10, 11]])
input4 = tf.constant([[12, 13], [14, 15]])

input = tf.stack([input1, input2, input3, input4])

# prepare indices for gather_nd
my_shape = tf.shape(input)[1:]
my_range = my_shape[0]*my_shape[1]
m = tf.range(0, my_range)
def get_inds(t, last_dim):
  return tf.convert_to_tensor([t // last_dim, t % last_dim])
inds = tf.map_fn(fn=lambda t: get_inds(t, my_shape[-1]), elems=m)
sh = tf.concat([my_shape, [2]], -1)
inds = tf.reshape(inds, sh)
mat0 = tf.zeros(my_shape, dtype=tf.int32)
mat0 = mat0[..., tf.newaxis]
mat1 = mat0 + 1
mat2 = mat0 + 2
mat3 = mat0 + 3
mat0 = tf.concat([mat0, inds], -1)
mat1 = tf.concat([mat1, inds], -1)
mat2 = tf.concat([mat2, inds], -1)
mat3 = tf.concat([mat3, inds], -1)
mat0 = tf.concat([mat0, mat1], 1)
mat1 = tf.concat([mat2, mat3], 1)
inds = tf.concat([mat0, mat1], 0)

res = tf.gather_nd(input, inds)
```

Preparing indices matrix is complicated. I didn't manage to simplify it